# iOS development/distribution certificate, missing private key

Tags: ios

I have problem when I try to upload new app version

[image]

Comment: Who ever created the developer credentials originally needs to go to the keychain on their computer and right click on the key(s) for private and public and export the key to a file. Then you just download that file on your computer and open it, and it will be added to your keychain.

You need to have both the private key (.pem file) and the certificate for your provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

In Enterprise Accounts there are only 2 distribution certificates allowed and you have to be careful: if you revoke an Enterprise certificate, all apps signed with that certificate will stop working immediately (after having Internet of course). So the only possible way to share an Enterprise account is that one person creates the certificate (incl. private key) and shares it with all participants. Before the certificate expires this person has to create the second one and share that with everybody so that they can sign on time a new release.

Like Dhaval commented, the one person can export the certificate and private key in the Keystore-App. There you can select and export certificate and key separately or mark both and export them together. Import is done the same way. If you only get the private key, you can also download the certificate in the developer portal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Certificates from your keychain got deleted and that's why this error is coming.

**Solution is** , just go to your Apple account open certificates and identifiers the go to your certificates and download the certificates which are related to this app and , download them and then double click on them to add to your keychain. now close your project and open it again and now go to certificates and signing option in Xcode and just uncheck and check again automatically manage signing. This will resolve your answer.